# cmd set env and run script

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I want to run from powershell a batch script that needs a environment variable before run.

This is what I tried.

`cmd.exe /c SET ENV_BASE_DIR='C:\Program Files\XY\Z 12.3' "&" "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\file.bat /d /p"`

Comment: I don't think you need quotes around the & and try putting everything on one line

Comment: @Marichyasana, the `&` indeed needs quoting or escaping as `\`&`, otherwise _PowerShell_ will interpret it, not `cmd.exe` (Windows PowerShell will complain that `&` is reserved for future use, PowerShell [Core] will treat it as the [background operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#background-operator-). The original command _is_ on one line, it's only broken in two as a posting artifact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid quoting headaches, consider (temporarily) setting the environment variable from PowerShell and then invoking the batch file directly:

```
$env:ENV_BASE_DIR = 'C:\Program Files\XY\Z 12.3'

C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\file.bat /d /p

$env:ENV_BASE_DIR = $null # remove the env. var again.
```

---

If you do want to solve this with a `cmd.exe` one-liner:

```
cmd.exe /c set ENV_BASE_DIR='C:\Program Files\XY\Z 12.3' `& C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\file.bat /d /p
```

- The `&` metacharacter is more simply escaped with `` ` `` (backtick), PowerShell's escape character.
- The batch file path and its arguments are passed as individual arguments.

---

As for what you tried:

Ultimately, the only problem with your command line was that you put double quotes around `C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\file.bat /d /p` *as a whole*, which caused `cmd.exe` to consider the entire string the executable path.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @KAN. I would expect the first one to work too, however; in what way did it not work? Note that if you quote your batch file path you must prepend `&`, the call operator (e.g.,  `& 'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\file.bat' /d /p`).

Answer (score 0):

I use it in `powershell`

```
$env:NODE_ENV="development"; yarn run db:migrate up
```

Attention, in this case in the current terminal the variable will be set globally, not only for this command. If you open another terminal, this variable will be absent there already